# Error: An API error occurred: missing_scope | How to get the userID with NodeJS (bolt Framework for Slack)

Tags: node.js, chatbot, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm creating a `slackbot` with `NodeJS` (bolt Framework) and I need to get the sender of the message that was sent to the bot.

My current approach is to get the information with `users.identity`, but every time I try to reinstall `identity.basic`

**I get this error:**

[image: error]

`"Invalid permissions requested invalid_scope"` on the reinstall page and when using identify instead,

I get this error in the console:

[image: error].

**Does anyone know what I could try, or is there another way to get the `userID` when the user sent a slash command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a user triggers your Slash Command Slack sends a data payload to your configured Request URL. That payload will include the `user_id` of the user who triggered the command.
(https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#app_command_handling).